# jQuery confusion: why does $("input").eq(0)(":checked") give "jQuery(...) is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am puzzled by this behavior. As I understand the docs, $("input") returns a jQuery object for all of the input elements in the DOM, and so $("input").eq(0) would return a jQuery object for the first input element in the DOM. And the ":checked" selector selects from the jQuery object all elements that are checked.

So I expected that `$("input").eq(0)(":checked")` would return a jQuery object of length 0 if the first input element was not checked, or a jQuery object of length 1 for the element itself if it was checked. What's wrong with my thinking? I realize this is really fundamental, but I can't figure it out. jQuery is an object, but I can normally call it like a function and pass it a string for a selector. But here I call a function that returns a jQuery object, but I can't call it with a string selector. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("input").eq(0)` returns a `jQuery` object, but you are trying to call it as a function with `(":checked")`. This is invalid, just like `({a: 1})()` (attempting to call an object like a function). `jQuery` itself is a function that you can call, but its return value is not.

Use `$('input').eq(0).is(':checked')` to check if the element matches the selector.

Or use `.filter(':checked')` to get all the elements that match the selector.

Comment: I guess its just the terminology. Everything returns a jQuery object, and if you look [here](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), it says "A jQuery object contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM) elements" and "The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array". Yet you say "jQuery itself is a function", and the quoted section also says "Most frequently, you will use the jQuery() function to create a jQuery object". So I'm still a liitle puzzled. But your solution of using .is(selector) is exactly what I was looking for, I've never used that function before! Thanks!

Comment: @sootsnoot A jQuery object is just an instance of `jQuery.fn.init` and is quite similar to an array. You cannot call an object as it is not a function. jQuery itself is a function, but that is distinct from what jQuery returns when called.

Comment: Thanks, that maybe helps a little. My use of javascript is quite shallow. Guess I need to learn about ".fn.init", That one always puzzles me when it shows up in devtools. If I got  comfortable with it, maybe my jQuery confusion would go away.